Manual install sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv
For an upcoming web project I am testing 24.04 server with MSSQL connectivity.
It's a LAMP environment with PHP 8.3.
So far I have managed to install (with a few tricks) msodbc driver and tools (V18). They show up in the modules list and sqlcmd is working.
I haven't found a way to install the php drivers yet, although MS says it should work.
What I'm getting is: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function _parseFeaturesHeaderFile() in /usr/share/php/OS/Guess.php.
Any ideas?

You asking for help without saying what you have actually done so far. From your question +managed to install (with a few tricks) + What tricks what have you done?

Got it running ;-)
Basically, the trick was convincing the system to install 22.04 stuff all the time.
I then took the Guess.php from a 22.04 and then I was able to install sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv and it worked. Plus a little manual work to get everything configured.
I can now connect from Ubuntu 24.04 to an external MSSQL server using sqlcmd, using php scrpting and also from the WP wpdatatables plugin. Project may start now.
